# Code for Optimistic Concurrency

Tags: c#, sql-server

I've a problem with a little program for my for my studies.
I need a basilar implementation for the optimistic concurrency.
I start from the example code in the Microsoft Documentation and I write a test case for check the Optimistic condition.
The code is this:

```
private void TestConcorrenza_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


   // Assumes connection is a valid SqlConnection.
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Id,Nome FROM DAti ORDER BY Id",FirstConnection);
    // The Update command checks for optimistic concurrency violations in the WHERE clause.
    adapter.UpdateCommand = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Dati Set Id = @Id, Nome = @Nome WHERE Id = @oldId AND Nome= @oldNome", FirstConnection);
    adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add( "@Id", SqlDbType.NChar, 5, "Id");
    adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@Nome", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30, "Nome");
    // Pass the original values to the WHERE clause parameters.
    SqlParameter parameter = adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@oldId", SqlDbType.NChar, 5, "Id");
    parameter.SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Original;
    parameter = adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@oldNome", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30, "Nome");
    parameter.SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Original;
    // Add the RowUpdated event handler.
    adapter.RowUpdated += new SqlRowUpdatedEventHandler(OnRowUpdated);
    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
    adapter.Fill(dataSet, "Dati");
    // Modify the DataSet contents.
    Update_for_Test();
    adapter.Update(dataSet, "Dati");
    foreach (DataRow dataRow in dataSet.Tables["Dati"].Rows)
    {
           if (dataRow.HasErrors)
           Console.WriteLine(dataRow [0] + "\n" + dataRow.RowError);
    }
    DataTable aTable = new DataTable();
    adapter.Fill(aTable);
    this.Test1.DataSource = aTable;
}



protected static void OnRowUpdated(object sender, SqlRowUpdatedEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.RecordsAffected == 0)
    {
        args.Row.RowError = "Optimistic Concurrency Violation Encountered";
        args.Status = UpdateStatus.SkipCurrentRow;
    }
}
```

This is the principal part and this is the test case:

```
public void Update_for_Test()
{
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Id,Nome FROM 
    Dati ORDER BY Id", SecondConnection);
    SqlDataAdapter ada= new SqlDataAdapter("UPDATE Dati SET  Nome 'Anna'                   WHERE Nome='Luca'", SecondConnection);
    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
    ada.Fill(dataSet, "Dati");
    adapter.Fill(dataSet, "Dati");
    DataTable aTable = new DataTable();
   adapter.Fill(aTable);
   this.Test2.DataSource = aTable;
}
```

I don't understand why the condition in the foreach is false.
Someone have an idea?
Thks a lot, Good job.

Comment: Why shouldn't this condition be false? Are you sure your dataRow has errors?

Comment: I think this condition is true if there is an error... but i repeat this is the code take from microsoft example i'm not sure it is correct...  advice for testing these condition?

Comment: This condition is true, if any of the dataRows has errors or the RowError property of the dataRow is not an empty string. What kind of error do you want to catch with this?

Comment: I think this condition is here for catch  the error rise from an external update on the row... But i'm not sure about this, do you like suggest me a condition for catch the optimistic error?

Comment: i see now an error in my text... i don't understand why the if condition don't swap to false..